# drop rows having more than one values using python

Tags: python

Suppose

| Column_A |
| -------- |
| AT    |
| CT    |
| A     |
| T     |
I want to drop rows having more than one character such as (AT and CT) rows and count only the remaining rows.
Please guide me on how to code using python.

Comment: You should explain more... or maybe share a sample file

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame((dict(base=x) for x in "AT CT A T".split()))
>>> df["length"] = df.base.apply(len)
>>> df
  base  length
0   AT       2
1   CT       2
2    A       1
3    T       1
>>> 
>>> df[df.length == 1]
  base  length
2    A       1
3    T       1
```

Or just use `df.base[df.length == 1]`
if you only want a single column.